# Return &str instead of std::borrow::Cow<'_, str>

Tags: string, rust

I want to update the variable input which is of type `&str`. How can I make the inner function return the `&str` instead of the `Cow`?

This may be not a problem with the language but with the regex-crate. Is there one that is more straightforward?

```
fn transform_the_expression() {

    fn create_formula<'t>(input: &'t str, re: Regex) -> std::borrow::Cow<'t, str> {
        let changed_string = re.replace(input, "1");
        return changed_string;
    }

    let mut input = "(a+(b*c))";
    use regex::Regex;
    let re = Regex::new(r"\([\w\d][/*+-^][\w\d]\)").unwrap();

    println!("input = {:?}", input);
    input = create_formula(input, re);
    println!("input = {:?}", input);
}
```

Comment: Why, though? You can get the reference from `Cow` by dereferencing it.

Comment: @ljedrz: presumably, so that `input = create_formula(input, re);` works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You **cannot**.

---

The cornerstone of Rust is **ownership**, which is a concept you need to understand.

A `&str` *borrows* but does not *own*, it refers to a piece of memory that someone else owns. The borrow-checker will ensure, at compile-time, that whoever owns the piece of memory that is referred to will live *longer* than `&str`, as otherwise `&str` would point into the ether.

In this case, think of:

- `String` being a cat
- `&str` being a hand-held device running a live-feed of this cat (which is followed by a tiny camera drone)

Obviously, you can only have a live-feed of the cat as long as it *lives*, after that, ...

And your question is asking:

> If I kill the cat, how do I still get a live-feed?

You cannot.

---

In your case, `re.replace` creates a `Cow<'t, str>`. If you look at the definition of `Cow` you'll notice that it is:

- either a `&str`
- or a `String`

It is a `&str` *only* if no replacement occurred, and otherwise it is a `String`.

You cannot know, statically, which it is, so you need to consider the "worst case" alternative: think of it as a `String`.

What's the lifetime of this `String`: it depends whether you return it from the function or not, if you don't, it cannot outlive the function's frame.

And if it doesn't outlive the function frame, you cannot have a live-feed that outlive the function frame.

---

So?

My advice is to use a `String`. It'll be vastly simpler:

```
fn transform_the_expression() {
    use regex::Regex;

    fn create_formula(input: &str, re: &Regex) -> String {
        re.replace(input, "1").into()
    }

    let mut input = String::from("(a+(b*c))");
    let re = Regex::new(r"\([\w\d][/*+-^][\w\d]\)").unwrap();

    println!("input = {:?}", input);
    input = create_formula(&input, &re);
    println!("input = {:?}", input);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. The function into() seems to be deprecated and replaced by into_owned(), at least borrows.rs doesn't contains it.

Comment: The function `into` is a bit hard to find, because it is automatically implemented. I advise you to check out `std::convert::From` and its evil twin `std::convert::Into`: for any implementation of `X::from(Y) -> X` you get an implementation of `Y::into(self) -> X` auto-magically.